# Constructing a query, for selecting a table with limit of associations

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have using the last too many hours trying to construct this sql query that i just can't wrap my head around.

I have three tables, with the following relations, i have removed the rest of the columns for simplicity.

```
- Jobs
id

- Company
id

- Offer
job_id
company_id
offer_type (either 'single' or 'voucher')

- Reservation
job_id
company_id
```

Context.

A user creates a job. Companies can make one or two offers (one of each type) on a job, a job is closed when a job gets offers from 3 different companies. Also a reservation can take one of the spots.

So i am trying to fetch all open jobs, for a listing to the company. That is all jobs which have received offers from 2 different companies.

As mentioned i have tried to come up with a query for this, so far i got.

```
;WITH company_offers AS
(
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON(offers.company_id) offers.company_id, 
    count(offers.company_id) as total,
    offers.job_id
  FROM offers 
  GROUP BY offers.company_id, offers.job_id
), 
counts AS 
(
  SELECT jobs.*, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM company_offers) as offer_count,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM reservations WHERE reservations.job_id = jobs.id) as reservation_count
  FROM jobs
  JOIN company_offers ON company_offers.job_id = jobs.id
  GROUP BY jobs.id
)

SELECT offer_count+reservation_count as total  
FROM counts
```

I have tried to fetch the offers by unique company id, in the first CTE. Then using the second CTE to count the results of the first, and also find the reservation. Then i add them together at last, and lastly i should make a condition that the total is less than 3.
But this doesn't return the expected result, in fact long from.

I would appreciate if someone could help me out, and explain aswell.

Let me know if you got question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some generic SQL could look like this:

```
select Jobs.id
from Jobs
left outer join Offer on Offer.job_id = Jobs.id
left outer join Reservation on Reservation.job_id = Jobs.id
group by Jobs.id
having count(distinct Offer.company_id) + count(distinct Reservation.company_id) < 3
```

If PostgreSQL does not like that `count(distinct ...)`, you may have to include an equivalent sub-query.

By the way: 
`SELECT DISTINCT ... GROUP BY ...`, i.e. `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`, usually does not work out.

Comment: I send you a virtual hug! Thank you so much!